# Xtext editor crashes when injecting ITypesystem from Xtext Typesystem Framework

Tags: xtext

I have implemented a Domain Specific Language(DSL) using [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) which contains expressions, so in order to check easily their validity I decided to use [Xtext-typesystem Framework](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-typesystem/).
I was trying to implement the examples given in this [tutorial](http://www.infoq.com/articles/xtext_ts), but when I use

```
@Inject   private ITypesystem ts;
```

and then try to run Launch Runtime Eclipse in order to check my rules' validity, editor won't open and I get many errors. Below there are some of them:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/lib/Procedures$Procedure1
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:243)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:96)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
```

...

```
org.eclipse.papyrus.core.services.ServiceNotFoundException: Can't get the current Eclipse Active Editor. No ServiceRegistry found.
at org.eclipse.papyrus.core.utils.ServiceUtilsForActionHandlers.getServiceRegistry(ServiceUtilsForActionHandlers.java:67)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.core.utils.ServiceUtilsForActionHandlers.getTransactionalEditingDomain(ServiceUtilsForActionHandlers.java:88)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.handlers.GraphicalCommandHandler.getEditingDomain(GraphicalCommandHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.handlers.LoadHandler.getCommand(LoadHandler.java:49)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.handlers.GraphicalCommandHandler.isEnabled(GraphicalCommandHandler.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.isEnabled(HandlerProxy.java:320)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.isEnabled(Command.java:833)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.setHandler(Command.java:965)
```

(What does Papyrus have to do with this?)

```
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+CTRL+I:Binding(ALT+CTRL+I,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.egit.ui.team.Ignore,Ignore,
    ,
    Category(org.eclipse.egit.ui.commandCategory,Git,null,true),
    org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.IgnoreActionHandler,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)Binding(ALT+CTRL+I,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.command.AddToSVNIgnoreCommand,Add to svn:ignore...,
    ,
    Category(org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.command.category,SVN,null,true),
    ,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

And lots lots other errors.
Any ideas about why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you introduced a (transitive?) dependency to the bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib. Please make sure that you import that one in your manifest and that you don't exclude it from your launch config. The eGit / SVN key binding conflict does not seem to be related to this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The bundle is imported in the manifest and in launch config.If I erase the "@Inject" the editor runs just fine(but i m not sure that typesystem rules work).I cant unserstand where is the problem with the injection.

Comment: Did you add a binding from ITypesystem to an implementation class?

Comment: No and unfortunately,I dont know how and where to do this.Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok! I found it!!It was in the tutorial but if you work for hours you dont see it!Thank you very very much!!You guys in here are awsome!